# Редирект системного трафика на внутренний прокси

Tags: linux, proxy, redirect, iptables

Подскажите, пожалуйста!
Есть запущенный в самой системе прокси, который доступен на порту 8080. Хочу, чтобы весь системный трафик шел через него( браузер, обновления различные( sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade, т.е:) ), хоть тот же wget google.ru и т.д. ), т.к. сам прокси может шифровать трафик. И дальше хотелось бы, чтобы уже сам зашифрованный трафик с прокси шел на удаленный хост.
Т.е. именно интересно, как настроить iptables, чтобы происходил редирект на 127.0.0.1:8080, а с 127.0.0.1:8080 уже все отправлялось во внешний мир.
Спасибо!

Comment: С помощью iptables это невозможно, он ничего не знает про протоколы прикладного уровня

Comment: @andreymal айпитаблес поможет в случае прозрачного сквида

Comment: @eri но это прокатит только с протоколами, которые знает сам сквид (остаётся надеяться, что автору только http и нужен)

Comment: @andreymal в вопросе только http (s)

Comment: @eri об этом явно не сказано, «весь системный трафик» это не только http (и даже отдельно взятый браузер использует не только http)

Answer (score 0):

Открываете Ваш ~/.bashrc или другой подходящий файл и пишите в нем где то такое

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080
https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:8080
export http_proxy
export https_proxy
```

большинство "нормальных программ" сразу подхватят такую прокси после перезагрузки.

если Ваша прокси вдруг хочет имя-пароль, делайте так

```
http_proxy=http://user:password@proxyserver.com:3128
```

Почитать больше - https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Главное проверить, что бы программа, которая обеспечивает прокси, не подхватила эту прокси, а то будет весело.

Comment: синтаксис встроенной команды export, описанной в posix, допускает и одновременное присвоение значения: [`$ export имя=значение`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export)

Comment: допускает. Но как всегда найдется очередной dash, который именно так не умеет

Comment: «Открываете Ваш ~/.bashrc». p.s. учитывать в ответе поведение posix-несовместимой оболочки вряд ли имеет смысл, когда речь о gnu/linux

Comment: вот не нужно копировать пол цитаты. Там есть вторая половина "или другой подходящий файл"

Comment: Есть ещё `all_proxy`.